# Propagate OpenTelemetry context through Google PubSub using Go

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub, open-telemetry

Using Go, how can I propagate the `OpenTelemetry context` through Google `PubSub`?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish that I implemented the `TextMapCarrier` interface

```
// TextMapCarrier is the storage medium used by a TextMapPropagator.
type TextMapCarrier interface {
    Get(key string) string
    Set(key string, value string)
    Keys() []string
}
```

The final code is:

```
package whatever

import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
    "context"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel"
)

const pubsubAttribPrefix = "whatever"

// PubsubMessageCarrier injects and extracts traces from a pubsub.Message.
type PubsubMessageCarrier struct {
    msg *pubsub.Message
}

// NewPubsubMessageCarrier creates a new PubsubMessageCarrier.
func NewPubsubMessageCarrier(msg *pubsub.Message) PubsubMessageCarrier {
    return PubsubMessageCarrier{msg: msg}
}

// Get retrieves a single value for a given key.
func (c PubsubMessageCarrier) Get(key string) string {
    return c.msg.Attributes[pubsubAttribPrefix+"_"+key]
}

// Set sets an attribute.
func (c PubsubMessageCarrier) Set(key, val string) {
    c.msg.Attributes[pubsubAttribPrefix+"_"+key] = val
}

// Keys returns a slice of all keys in the carrier.
func (c PubsubMessageCarrier) Keys() []string {
    i := 0
    out := make([]string, len(c.msg.Attributes))
    for k := range c.msg.Attributes {
        out[i] = k
        i++
    }
    return out
}

func PubSubMessageInjectContext(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
    otel.GetTextMapPropagator().Inject(ctx, NewPubsubMessageCarrier(msg))
}

func PubSubMessageExtractContext(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) context.Context {
    return otel.GetTextMapPropagator().Extract(ctx, NewPubsubMessageCarrier(msg))
}
```

So all that is left is to feed the latest `context` from the `span` and the `PubSub` message to `PubSubMessageInjectContext`. This will inject the data to the message.

On the other side feed the new `context` with the received `message` to extract the data. And use the output `context` to create a new `span`.

**Note**, this does not provide attributes that need to be added to the designated span. like `semconv.MessagingDestinationKindTopic`

#### It still not battle tested though the basics are here

**Credit**, [Alex Hong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9932532/alex-hong) from the Google dev team.  [code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/pull/5034)